Set sanity decorators depending on the type
Is there any way to conditionally set decorators depending on the current type?
Something like this isProject:


export default {
  name: 'textContent',
  title: 'Text Content',
  type: 'array',
  of: [
    {
      type: 'block',
      styles: [
        {title: 'Normal', value: 'normal'},
        {title: 'Large', value: 'h4'},
      ],
      lists: [{title: 'Bullet', value: 'bullet'}],
      marks: {
        decorators: isProject ? workDecorators : defaultDecorators,
      }
    }
  ]
}



